# Matlab function to generate best fit line (r2 and m) for x and y with error bars

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

Does anyone know of a MATLAB function that takes in csv data (for columns: x, x_err, y, y_err), performs a best fit linear regression, and churns out r2 and m? A key here is that it accepts data error in addition to data.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_least_squares

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 separate questions here.

For reading the file, use the function [csvead](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/csvread.html;jsessionid=b73edf729ec683a552c0621041f3).
In order to fit the line and extract `R^2` information, use [polyfit](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html).

Comment: Thanks. Can polyfit accept error information in addition to x and y data?